# Macro factory, passing on star arguments

Tags: xparse, starred-version

I want to define a set of macros, with similar behaviour but applied to different symbols. To avoid repetitions, I thought it would be a good idea to generate them programmatically from a template.

I have a bunch of quantities

1. with general indices (`\idx`) applied to them,
2. but I occasionally need variations of this index (e.g., for defining recurrence relations);
3. or to scrap the automatic index altogether and replace it with something else.

I thought of using a `O{\idx}` argument type, but I do not like this solution, as I would like to especially restate `\idx` for `2.`. It seems like a star argument could be useful here.

This is why I came up with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand\idx{}{j}
\NewDocumentCommand\pmatstar{mm}{#1_{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand\pmatnostar{mm}{#1_{\idx#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand\matnum{smO{}}{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \pmatstar{#2}{#3}
    }{
        \pmatnostar{#2}{#3}
    }
}

%%%%%
% What I do not know how to do
%
% \NewDocumentCommand\specmatnum{mm}{...}
% \spectmatnum{mlow}{L}
% \spectmatnum{mupp}{U}
% ...
%
%%%%%

%%%%%
% This is what I want to avoid
%
% \NewDocumentCommand\mlow{sO{}}{
%     \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
%         \pmatstar{L}{#2}
%     }{
%         \pmatnostar{L}{#2}
%     }
% }
% \NewDocumentCommand\mupp{sO{}}{
%     \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
%         \pmatstar{U}{#2}
%     }{
%         \pmatnostar{U}{#2}
%     }
% }
% ...
%
%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\text{Default: } &\matnum{L}\\
\text{No star, modified default: } &\matnum{L}[+1]\\
\text{Star, no optional argument: } &\matnum*{L}\\
\text{Star, optional '2': } &\matnum*{L}[2]
\end{align*}

%%%%%
% How I would like to be able to replicate the above example without calling \matnum directly
%
% \mlow
% \mlow[+1]
% \mlow*
% \mlow*[2]
%
%%%%%

\end{document}
```

[image: Example output]

My question being, how not to duplicate the definition of `\matnum` for all my symbols? The main difficulty for me being the passing of the `*`, without rewriting the `\IfBooleanTF{}{}{}`; which nullifies the point of having `\matnum` in the first place. I think the rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand\idx{}{j}
\NewDocumentCommand\matnum{msO{}}{#1_{\IfBooleanF{#2}{\idx}#3}}

\NewDocumentCommand\specmatnum{mm}{%
 \ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{#1}{}{\matnum{#2}}}

\specmatnum{mlow}{L}
\specmatnum{mupp}{U}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\text{Default: } &\mlow\\
\text{No star, modified default: } &\mlow[+1]\\
\text{Star, no optional argument: } &\mlow*\\
\text{Star, optional '2': } &\mlow*[2]
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work brilliantly when built on Overleaf. However, I cannot get it to work on my own machine, which sports a more recent version of TeX Live (`format=lualatex 2022.11.10` against `format=lualatex 2022.8.9`). `ExpandArgs` seems to be a fairly new addition? It does not appear on the 2021-04-12 version of New LaTeX methods for authors. I do have it defined it `latex.ltx` and `latexrelease.sty`, under `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev`. I have manual entries, but no binaries for the *-dev versions. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Aubergine you have that backwards, it works on recent releases but not on your older one. If you can not update your machine to texlive 2022 then replace `\ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{#1}` by `\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1\endcsname`

Comment: @Aubergine or simpler use the syntax `\specmatnum{\mlow}{L}` and `\NewDocumentCommand#1`  the expansion control is just for the requested syntax with no `\ ` (which is a strange choice anyway as you use the command with a `\ `)

Answer (score 3):

Write down what you want to abstract and it becomes simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% we want that
% \spectmatnum{\mlow}{L}
% defines \mlow so
% \mlow -> L_{j}
% \mlow[+1] -> L_{j+1}
% \mlow* -> L
% \mlow*[2] -> L_{2}
%
% \NewDocumentCommand{\mlow}{so}{%
%   L%
%   \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
%     \IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}%
%   }{%
%     _{\idx\IfValueT{#2}{#2}}%
%   }%
% }

\NewDocumentCommand{\spectmatnum}{mm}{%
  % #1 = command name
  % #2 = letter
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{so}{%
    #2%
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}{%
      \IfValueT{##2}{_{##2}}%
    }{%
      _{\idx\IfValueT{##2}{##2}}%
    }%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\idx}{}{j}

\spectmatnum{\mlow}{L}
\spectmatnum{\mupp}{U}



\begin{document}

$\mlow\quad\mlow[+1]\quad\mlow*\quad\mlow*[2]$

$\mupp\quad\mupp[+1]\quad\mupp*\quad\mupp*[2]$

%%% comparison with \matnum
\NewDocumentCommand\matnum{msO{}}{#1_{\IfBooleanF{#2}{\idx}#3}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MLOW}{}{\matnum{L}}

$\mlow*|$

$\MLOW*|$

\end{document}
```

The parameters in the inner `\NewDocumentCommand` become `##1` and `##2`, whereas `#1` and `#2` refer to the argument to the outer one.

Since `\spectmatnum` defines a command, just give the command as argument, not just the name.

Why not `sO{\idx}` as the argument specifier? You can see the reason at the bottom, where the presence of an unwanted space is shown.

[image]